# How to detect movement within a specific area with Python Opencv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

Currently I have an algorithm using Python and OpenCV that detects geometrical shapes and calculates its length (without accuracy).

But I need to make that detection within a specific area, in this case it would be inside a rectangle that I draw with the `cv2.rect` function but I have no idea how to do it and I couldn't find any information on how to do it on the internet.

I am using `python 3.7` and `OpenCV 3`

Can someone help me?

[image: description of what I want to achieve]

Comment: Use only the region of you image covered by your rectangle to further processing.

Comment: I still do not understand how to do it, I am a beginner in OpenCV. Any function that you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Python, you can simply slice the image on the rectangle.

```py
x, y, w, h = cv2.selectROI(window_name, image)  # or something
img_cropped = img[y:y+h, x:x+h]
```

You can also check out [this tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/how-to-select-a-bounding-box-roi-in-opencv-cpp-python/)

Comment: I need it to be in real time: / ... focusing the Figures only inside the square that processes them ... I'm still investigating

Comment: Great answer , you can use `img_cropped` to apply the motion detection in real time.

Comment: Good idea Amine although I found this tutorial that apparently is what I need.  thank you    https://medium.com/beyondlabsey/creating-a-simple-region-of-interest-roi-inside-a-video-streaming-using-opencv-in-python-30fd671350e0

Answer (score 0):

Since images are really just arrays, you can also directly select a region of interest using slices, like this:

```
import cv2
frame = cv2.imread(image)

frame[50:100, 300:600]
```

This will select a region of x ranging from 50 to 100, and y from 300 to 600.    In your case, you could pass in the coordinates you use to draw the rectangle.